# Detect changing of the select list value with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried using `ng-change` on `select` but the problem is, I need to send `ticket.id` to the method but, `ticket.name` to model.

```
<select name="ticketAttendeeMapping"
        ng-model="attendee.ticketTypeName"
        class="form-control">
    <option ng-repeat="ticket in inTransitionTickets | filter: greaterThan('countRemaining', 0)"
            ng-value="ticket.name"
            ng-click="onAttendeeTicketmapping(ticket.id, $parent.$index)">
    {{ticket.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

I also tried doing this:

```
<select name="ticketAttendeeMapping"
        ng-model="attendee.ticketTypeName" class="form-control"
        ng-options="ticket.name as ticket.name for ticket in inTransitionTickets | filter: greaterThan('countRemaining', 0)"
        ng-change="onAttendeeTicketmapping(ticket.id, $index)">
    <option value="" disabled>Choose Your Ticket</option>
</select>
```

Comment: is the `ticket.name` unique?

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt yes `ticket.name` and `ticket.id` is unique for each `ticket`.

Comment: did u try ng-options?

Comment: what are you doing in the `onAttendeeTicketmapping` function?

Comment: @RishiPrakash I did, updated the question please check.

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt I am populating my Attendee form with custom questions depending upon Ticket Id, each question have one or more ticketId when that ticket is selected that question will be asked,

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: @ArpitGoyal why kind of problem are you facing?

Comment: @RishiPrakash `ng-click` is not working with option

Comment: @HuyHoangPham `ng-click` is not working with option, not getting any error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to just use the object in the model:

```
<select name="ticketAttendeeMapping" ng-model="attendee.ticket" class="form-control" ng-options="ticket.name for ticket in inTransitionTickets" ng-change="change(attendee.ticket.id)">
</select>
```

Then you can access the name by using `$scope.attendee.ticket.name` and you can access the id by using `$scope.attendee.ticket.id`

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jpfInCaMEHocDfZ8uK4p?p=preview)

Comment: You need to update `ng-options="ticket.name for ticket in inTransitionTickets"` to `ng-options="ticket for ticket in inTransitionTickets`"

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt no I don't. Syntax is `label for value in array`: [AngularDocs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Answer (score 1):

try to do this:

```
  <select name="ticketAttendeeMapping" ng-model="attendee.ticketTypeName" class="form-control" ng-options="ticket.name as ticket for ticket in inTransitionTickets | filter: greaterThan('countRemaining', 0)" ng-change="onAttendeeTicketmapping(attendee.ticketTypeName, $index)">
        <option value="" disabled>Choose Your Ticket</option>
    </select>
```

now you will get ticket i.e."attendee.ticketTypeName" object in ur ng-change method. where u can get its "id"

Comment: @sheelpriy `ng-change="onAttendeeTicketmapping(attendee.ticketTypeName, $index)"` this will result into nothing as I need ticket.id in method and even if try using id from ticket object it will not as there's not ticket in scope ?

Comment: you will get it in attendee.ticketTypeName object which will be passed in your ng-change method. ...  when i say ticket object it means ticket object will be in "attendee.ticketTypeName"

Comment: Syntax of ng-option::  label for value in array: ur model binds with value.. that is "ticket" object

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, If what I have done here is what was originally asked by OP.
We can't use `ng-options` here simply!!
because while we use "`ng-options`" it restricts our access to current selected Json element to the properties explicitly mentioned in `ng-options`, on the contrary `ng-repeat` gives you complete access to current Object.

```
<select name="ticketAttendeeMapping"
        ng-model="SelectedTicketNameFromngModel"
        class="form-control">
    <option ng-repeat="ticket in ticketJson "
            ng-value="ticket.name"
            ng-click="alertMe(ticket.id)">
    {{ticket.name}}
    </option>
</select>


$scope.SelectedTicketNameFromngModel = '';
    $scope.selectTicketIdFromMethod = '';
    $scope.ticketJson = [{'name':'tick1','id':'t1'},{'name':'tick2','id':'t2'},{'name':'tick3','id':'t3'}];


    $scope.alertMe = function(tId){
               $scope.selectTicketIdFromMethod = tId;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16124/

[image]

Comment: "ticker Id========" does not changes to any value on selection that is what I meant when I said ng-click is not working.

Comment: ticker id is changing on click. I tested it properly. what error do you see on console of firebug??

Comment: Yes, your jsfiddle is working properly. Just  add dependency of AngularJS from left bar Framework and extensions